# wx.ProgressDialog + py2exe leads to application crash

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, py2exe

This simple code runs very well :

```
import wx
app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
test = wx.ProgressDialog('Test', 'Test', maximum = 20, parent = frame, style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
app.MainLoop()
```

However, when compiling/packing it into an executable with `py2exe`...

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(script_args = ['py2exe'], windows=[{'script':'progressdlgprobblem.py'}],  
   options = {'py2exe': {'compressed':1,'bundle_files': 1}}, zipfile = None)
```

... then the `.exe` file crashes.

**What could be the cause of this crash? Does `wx.ProgressDialog` require some specific additional elements in order to be used with `py2exe`?**

---

*Addendum 1* : when I remove the `style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT`, there is no more crash. How can the crash come from the `style` ?
But then, the *styling*  is XP-style when launching from the `.exe` :

[image]

and different to the styling I get when launching from the `.py` (without py2exe) :

[image]

---

*Addendum 2* : when I remove the `'bundle_files': 1`, no more crash.
But I would like to keep this bundling into one file only ! **How can this bundling into a single .exe file be the cause of this crash ?**

*Addendum 3* : A big part of the problem is solved by using wx.Python 3.0.1.0b instead of 3.0.0.0 (more details soon).

Comment: Any detail on the crash ?

Comment: A standard dialogbox "test.exe has stopped working", without any log message

Comment: Try making a shortcut to the resulting exe with `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "path-to-your-exe"` in the Target.   With luck, a command window will stay open showing you the traceback...

Comment: It works on `OS: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1`, `Python: 2.7.3`, `wxPython: 2.8.12.1`, `py2exe: 0.6.9`.

Comment: Also works on `OS: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1`, `Python: 3.3.3`, `wxPython: 3.0.1.dev75711 msw (phoenix)`, `cx_Freeze: 4.3.2`.

Comment: thanks @Fensiko. Does it work with both exactly the *same* sample code  and the same py2exe code ? (or did you modify the py2exe parameters) ?

Comment: The second one is with cx_freeze as py2exe is not available for Python 3. Any chance that you use new official wxPython 3.x?

Comment: Belatedly: it works using bbfreeze intead of py2exe with python 2.7.2 on Win7, as well, FWIW :(

Comment: `print wx.__version__` gives me `3.0.0.0` and Python version is 2.7.5 (Anaconda 1.7.0 (32-bit))

Comment: py2exe hasn't been updated in years. I would try using bb_freeze or cx_freeze instead.

Comment: I finally found this error in the `py2exe` traceback : `The following modules appear to be missing` `['IronPythonConsole', 'System', 'System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard', '_scproxy', 'clr', 'console', 'modes.editingmodes', 'pyreadline.keysyms.make_KeyPress', 'pyreadline.keysyms.make_KeyPress_from_keydescr', 'pyreadline.keysyms.make_keyinfo', 'pyreadline.keysyms.make_keysym', 'startup']`... Why these modules ?

Comment: Can you clarify about the traceback: is it the case that py2exe actually failed, and that is why your exe won't run?

Comment: In fact I noticed that this traceback always happens when I use py2exe, even for apps that finally don't crash. So this traceback here is not revelant for the problem here.

There is no traceback when running the .exe : the app crashes before displaying anything

Comment: I do not think that missing modules matter. Can you try older version of wxPython?

Comment: @Fenikso I tried with `wxPython 2.8.1`, once again the .py file works. But once compiled with py2exe, the .exe produces an error (no more a crash, it's better ;)). Here is the traceback : http://pastebin.com/QMUZbftN

Comment: Man, there is something seriously wrong with your environment. Above I have verified it working with two distinct environment settings. I have never encountered similar traceback, but I am using cx_freeze for about 2 years now - not looking back. Anyway, creating one packed exe is a bad idea because it really is a hack. Some antivirus programs may mess with it, slow the startup A LOT etc. If you plan to give the app to the public, `bundle_files` is seriously bad idea anyway. Try disabling your antivirus for your test. Try disabling `bundle_files` option. Try cx_freeze.

Comment: Thanks @Fensiko for your ideas. I will try `cx_freeze`. But I really like the clean aspect of having only a few files or only one file (`bundle_files=1`), it is cleaner for the final user.

Comment: Huh, you misspell my nickname, so I am not notified about your comments. To answer, that idea is just wrong. The application is composed of main executable which is statically linked and then a lot of dynamically linked libraries in `*.dll` and `*.pyd` files. Just open your `Program Files` and let me know how many of the apps are one `.exe`. For a reason... When you pack everything in one `exe` by `py2exe`, it is a HACK to do that. It packs it as part of `exe` and then, when you try to run it, it unpacks. It takes time and it is so weird that it can be considered malicious by anti-virus.

Comment: Now it is certain, that for deployment it is not nice to have a directory instead of one file. That is why we have installers. So you can pack the whole directory in one file and during installation you can give user a nice icons, Start menu etc. So the right way by the way Windows is designed is to generate a directory instead of packed exe, create an installer for your app and let user install it (and uninstall if they wish). Create shortcuts for them, so they do not care about the mess in the install directory. The same way as all the mainstream apps do.

Comment: A big part of the problem is solved by using wx.Python 3.0.1.0b instead of 3.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

py2exe (0.6.9) is pretty outdated and doesn't handle newer Windows versions all that well without some additional changes. Specifically, it will by default include some Windows system DLLs which never should be bundled. To prevent this, try altering your setup script as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# Exclude system DLLs
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("gdiplus.dll", 
                                              "mfc90.dll"):
        return 0
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("powrprof.dll", ) or \
       os.path.basename(pathname).lower().startswith("api-ms-win-"):
        return 1
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname)
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL

# Add the MS VC9 CRT and common controls manifest as resource to the exe
manifest = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    version="0.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="Enter program name here"
    type="win32"
  />
  <description>Enter program description here</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
         type="win32"
         name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
         version="6.0.0.0"
         processorArchitecture="x86"
         publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
         language="*"
       />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
         type="win32"
         name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
         version="9.0.21022.8"
         processorArchitecture="x86"
         publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"
       />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
'''

setup(script_args=['py2exe'],
      windows=[{'script': 'progressdlgprobblem.py',
                'other_resources': [(24, 1, manifest)]}],  
      options = {'py2exe': {'compressed': 1,
                            'dll_excludes': ['iertutil.dll', 
                                             'MPR.dll',
                                             'msvcm90.dll', 
                                             'msvcp90.dll', 
                                             'msvcr90.dll', 
                                             'mswsock.dll',
                                             'urlmon.dll',
                                             'w9xpopen.exe'],
                            'bundle_files': 1}},
      zipfile=None)
```

For best interoperability, you'll also want to copy Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest, msvcm90.dll, msvcp90.dll, and msvcr90.dll from C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91 (the directory name may be slightly different, but the correct version 9.0.21022.8 is important) to your exe's directory so users don't need to install the right version of the MS VC9 CRT themselves.

Alternatively to all of this, you could try PyInstaller which automatically handles assembly dependencies and excludes system DLLs by default.

Answer (score 1):

Had issues with the `ProgressDialog` example and added progress and cleanup, but is otherwise unchanged.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
max_count = 8
dlg = wx.ProgressDialog('Test caption', 'Test text', maximum = max_count, parent = frame, style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)

keepGoing = True # progress routine from wxPython demo
count = 0

while keepGoing and count < max_count:
    count += 1
    wx.MilliSleep(125)
    wx.Yield()
    (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count, 'progress: {0} %'.format(count * 100.0/max_count))        

dlg.Destroy() # proper cleanup otherwise process has to be killed
frame.Destroy()

app.MainLoop()
```

Freezing with `py2exe` is a pain in the ass but delivers IMHO still nice result for the Windows platform. Much of the settings is try-and-error. In the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Py2exe%20with%20Python2.6) there is a good description/explanation how to manage the SxS assembly and the manifest.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""manifest fixes NT-theming and including MSVC runtime issue"""

"""
# Recipe from
http://wiki.wxpython.org/Py2exe%20with%20Python2.6
"""

manifest = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    version="5.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="%(prog)s"
    type="win32"
  />
  <description>%(prog)s</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
            level="asInvoker"
            uiAccess="false">
        </requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
            version="9.0.21022.8"
            processorArchitecture="x86"
            publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
      </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
"""

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
dll_excludes = [
    'w9xpopen.exe',
   'MSVCP90.dll' # reason see link to wxPython-wiki above
]
setup(script_args = ['py2exe'], windows=[{'script':'progressdlg.py',#
                                          "other_resources": [(24, 1, manifest)]}],   # manifest added
   options = {'py2exe': {'compressed':1,'bundle_files': 1, 'dll_excludes': dll_excludes,
                         }}, zipfile = None)
```

At least on my machine (WinXP 7 + wxPython 2.9.5.0) this setup (`python setup.py py2exe`) produces:

- A single `.EXE`
- Correct theming also when frozen
- No crashes, full usability, use style flags you like

The example will at least work on your machine (where the `MSCV` runtimes are installed already). For a more complete list of excludes see the parallel thread in [wxPython-users]`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/vrd-0cpiH1E`.

The [`esky`](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) library has fixes for this quirks already included and offers live-updating for `wx`-Apps, but you may or may not like the different project structure it is setting up.

Side Note: I was not able to reproduce your crash on wxPython 2.9.5.0 (even without the assembly). I had crashes on XP when freezing with 3.0.0.0 on a Win8 machine, but this should be solved in 3.0.1 according to Robin (see `https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/8OeBfxTC9Xo`).

Side note 2: This seems to be a problem with wxPython 3.0.0.0 (classic). At my XP machine this examples crashes even if not frozen. If upgrading to [wxPython 3.0.1 (phoenix)](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.1.dev75864-py2.7-win32.egg) then it works again (both unfrozen and py2exe'd). The frozen single-file `EXE` runs without issues on Windows8, 64 bit, and WinXP with correct theme.

Comment: I exactly followed your steps (on Win7 x64 + (Anaconda) Python 2.7 x86 + wxPython 3.0.0.0), and ... crash ! :( I still give you the bounty, and thanks for the time spent anyway !
Well, now give up with `bundle_files : 1` and the fact of having a single `.exe`...

Comment: I was hoping to snatch an "Accepted", but this is not possible with your question . wxPython 3.0.0.0 seems to be broken in that regard. (see side note 2).

Comment: Bounty is far better than Accepted here ;)
Yes maybe it will be solved in a next version... Or maybe this problem will completely disappear if I format my hard disk and reinstall all Python + modules on my computer one day... For now I disabled `bundle_files = 1`.